# jsperf testing setInterval() vs requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript, performance, jsperf

Can someone explain why `turnEvenOld(250, 250)`(0.089ms) runs much much more faster than `turnEvent(250, 250)`(0.447ms)?

I thought using `requestAnimationFrame()` was a lot faster and cheaper to run than `setInterval()`?

**setInterval():**

```
var turnEventOLD = function turnEvent(AnX, AnY) {
    ----VARIABLES----
    temp = setInterval(myAnimation1, 1000/60);
    function myAnimation1() {
        ----DRAWINGCANVAS------
        -----
        ----CONDITIONS--------
        if (one301 && one401) {
            clearInterval(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

**requestAnimationFrame():**

```
var turnEvent = function turnEvent(AnX, AnY) {
   ----VARIABLES-----
    function render() {
        ----DRAWING CANVAS-----
        ------
        ----CONDITIONS---------
        if (one301 && one401) {
            ---stop requestAnimation--
        }
    }
    (function animloop(){
        ----CONDTION-----
        requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
        render();
    })();
}
```

Comment: turnEventOLD does no work (except defering a function), turnEvent calls render before it's done. also keep in mind that requestAnimationFrame() could result in running more than 60 renders a second, and thus use more CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequestAnimation frame is not necessarily "faster" than setInterval. It actually does something different.

setInterval will wait a given number of milliseconds while requestAnimationFrame will wait until the page is ready to repaint.  Depending on the time in your setInterval call, the time setInterval waits could be shorter or longer than the time until the next repaint.

It is better to use requestAnimationFrame for animations so you're sure you change the visual elements before the next repaint instead of being potentially out of synch with the page repaints.

Comment: I just don't understand the performance or efficiency gain? That doesnt matter in this case?

Comment: It's not that important which one is more efficient, it's more about making sure you're changing visuals at the right time. If your intervals are faster than repaints, you'll drop frames. If your intervals are slower than repaints, you'll get repeated frames.  If you're close to the repainting speed, it's worse, because you'll get a mix of missed frames and doubled frames, and your animation won't look as smooth. You'll usually get a bit of jitter. Using requestAnimationFrame makes sure you're lined up exactly with the repaints.

Comment: thank you for the explanation :-). Now I understand it's purpose much better. I am happy with the result. Learning each day :D

Comment: @MarkFuzz I just replaced `setInterval()` that's being used to animate a bunch of components with `requestAnimationFrame()`, and the performance of requestAnimationFrame seems terrible in Chrome.  I was surprised.  Maybe it's just more costly to enqueue the callback each time with requestAnimationFrame where as with setInterval it only has to be enqueued when the timer is started?

Comment: I haven't seen something say this explicitly, but I get the impression `requestAnimationFrame()` was intended more for the case where a single callback performs all the animation on the page (esp. for a video game, for example) rather than being used by a bunch of components that animate themselves independently.